# How to stop go block in ClojureScript / core.async?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Is there an elegant way to stop a running go block?

(without introducing a flag and polluting the code with checks/branches)

```
(ns example
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])
  (:require        [cljs.core.async        :refer [<! timeout]]))

(defn some-long-task []
  (go
    (println "entering")

    ; some complex long-running task (e.g. fetching something via network)
    (<! (timeout 1000)) 
    (<! (timeout 1000))
    (<! (timeout 1000))
    (<! (timeout 1000))

    (println "leaving")))

; run the task
(def task (some-long-task))

; later, realize we no longer need the result and want to cancel it 
; (stop! task)
```

Comment: `(close! task)` maybe ? - google first result.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this is not possible with core.async today. What you get back from creating a `go` block is a normal channel what the result of the block will be put on, though this does not give you any handle to the actual block itself.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in Arthur's answer, you cannot terminate a `go` block immediately, but you since your example indicates a multi-phased task (using sub-tasks), an approach like this might work:

```
(defn task-processor
  "Takes an initial state value and number of tasks (fns). Puts tasks
  on a work queue channel and then executes them in a go-loop, with
  each task passed the current state. A task's return value is used as
  input for next task. When all tasks are processed or queue has been
  closed, places current result/state onto a result channel. To allow
  nil values, result is wrapped in a map:

  {:value state :complete? true/false}

  This fn returns a map of {:queue queue-chan :result result-chan}"
  [init & tasks]
  (assert (pos? (count tasks)))
  (let [queue  (chan)
        result (chan)]
    (async/onto-chan queue tasks)
    (go-loop [state init, i 0]
      (if-let [task (<! queue)]
        (recur (task state) (inc i))
        (do (prn "task queue finished/terminated")
            (>! result {:value state :complete? (== i (count tasks))}))))
    {:queue  queue
     :result result}))

(defn dummy-task [x] (prn :task x) (Thread/sleep 1000) (inc x))

;; kick of tasks
(def proc (apply task-processor 0 (repeat 100 dummy-task)))

;; result handler
(go
  (let [res (<! (:result proc))]
    (prn :final-result res)))

;; to stop the queue after current task is complete
;; in this example it might take up to an additional second
;; for the terminated result to be delivered
(close! (:queue proc))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use future and future-cancel for such task.

```
(def f (future (while (not (Thread/interrupted)) (your-function ... ))))
(future-cancel f)
```

[Why do cancelled Clojure futures continue using CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520394/why-do-cancelled-clojure-futures-continue-using-cpu/14540878#14540878)